# Is there any Linux Distro based on BSD

Tags: linux, bsd

I have hp probook 4530s. I have tried variety of OS on this but after using 10-15mins its screen flicks and the system hangs. Check the attached screenshot
[image]

This screen flicks for all windows OSs, Linux (Mint, Ubuntu etc) But laptop works perfectly fine when installing BSD based systems like Mac OSX, PCFreeBSD. I am not sure whats the cause behind the scenes. Can someone please tell me any Linux distro which is based on BSD??

Answer (score 2):

[Debian kFreeBSD](https://debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/) is of course based upon FreeBSD.

**But that is merely papering over your problem.**

If your system truly [behaves like this](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/I-sometimes-get-a-wrecked-display-and-the-PC-get-stuck-on/td-p/1043425) with both Linux and Windows, then it probably doesn't hit this fault with PC-BSD and FreeBSD only by accident.

Comment: accident!!! strange

Comment: I dont blv its accident. I sometimes got this error while I just started the installation process of Linux Mint. There is some architecture difference due to which these systems have problems and BSD has not

Answer (score 0):

Linux and BSD are two totally different operating systems.  BSD is a licensed variant of UNIX, while Linux was developed independently, but made to have a UNIX feel.

Your problems are probably not based around the distribution, but perhaps a hardware problem.  I would suspect memory and you probably should run [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) to be sure.

I had a similar issue recently.  I have a mediacenter PC that was running Linux and was fairly stable.  It locked up a couple of times, but I didnt think much of it.  I went to install Windows and I couldnt get past the install screen.  That is very common with bad memory.  I ran Memtest86 and saw bad memory.

Comment: I ran memtest86. All tests passed OK.